# Python socket programmed web server doesnt send information to browser

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I create a simple web server using python socket programming. When I access it using a socket programmed client I get this response (which seems to be good):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK        
Content-Length: 145    
Content-Type: text/html

"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Links</h2>
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a></p>

</body>
</html>"""
```

However, when I try to access 127.0.0.1:80  on the browser it says:

> 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Web Server Code:

```
import socket
import os

def get_content_type(filename):
    index = filename.rfind('.')
    extension = filename[index+1:len(filename)]
    if(extension == 'txt' or extension == 'html'):
        return 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
    elif(extension == 'jpg'):
        return 'Content Type: image/jpeg\n'
    elif(extension == 'js'):
        return 'Content Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF 8\n'
    elif(extension == 'css'):
        return 'Content Type: text/css\n'
    pass


def check_client_request(client_request):
    request_splitted = client_request.split()
    if(len(request_splitted) != 3):
        return False
    if(request_splitted[0] != 'GET'):
        return False
    if(request_splitted[1].find('http://') != 0):
        return False
    if(request_splitted[1].count('/') < 3):
        return False
    if(request_splitted[2] != 'HTTP/1.1\\r\\n'):
        return False
    return True


def recieve_client_request(client_socket):
    client_request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    return client_request.decode('utf-8')


def handle_client_request(request):
    try:
        filename = request.split()[1].split('/')[3]
    except:
        return 'File not found'
    if(filename == ''):
        filename = 'index.html'
    path = f'C:\\Users\\Eitan\\Desktop\\Python-Course\\SOCKETWEBSERVER\\{filename}'
    print(path)
    response = ''
    if(os.path.isfile(path)):
        try:
            requested_file = open(path, 'r')
            file_content = requested_file.read()
            requested_file.close()
            response = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n'
            content_length = len(file_content.encode('utf-8'))
            response += f'Content-Length: {content_length}\n'
            response += get_content_type(filename)
            response += '\n'
            response += f'"""{file_content}"""'

        except:
            response = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n'
    else:
        response = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n'

    return response


def send_response(client_socket, response):
    try:
        client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
        print('Response Sent')
    except:
        print('Couldnt send response.')


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    while True:
        client_socket = server_socket.accept()[0]
        client_request = recieve_client_request(client_socket)
        if(check_client_request(client_request)):
            response = handle_client_request(client_request)
            send_response(client_socket, response)
            client_socket.close()
        else:
            client_socket.close()      

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Client Code:

```
import socket

def main():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 80))
    request = input("Command: ").encode('utf-8')
    client_socket.send(request)
    response = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(response.decode('utf-8'))

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(request_splitted[1].find('http://') != 0):
    return False
```

You expect the browser to send a request like this

```
 GET http://domain/page HTTP/1.1
 ...
```

But, a normal HTTP request does not include protocol and host but only the page, i.e. it looks like this

```
 GET /page HTTP/1.1
 ...
```

Since you treat the valid request from the browser as invalid you close the connection and thus no response is sent to the browser.

Note that HTTP is not that simple as it might look. There is an actual standard for this which is quite long and which you are expected to follow when implementing a HTTP server or client.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will look into the standard.